# Simulate scrolling on iOS, with Javascript, on an iframe with hidden scrollbars

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe

I have an iframe with scrolling="no" and overflow: hidden;

I need to be able to simulate scrolling with JavaScript alone from either the parent window or within the iframe (it doesn't matter).

Am testing on iOS 8 (iPhone) and I can't seem to be able to move the iframe through a touchmove event handler (or any way for that matter - even tried a setInterval).

For the code that moves the iFrame, I tried both window.scrollBy() and window.scrollTo() from within the iframe. I debugged and had no exceptions. I may be missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it by css only. try the following to the `selectors` where you want that touch move.

```
webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* lets it scroll lazy */
```

but you've to use the `overflow: auto` to get it working. If you wish to keep it within certain `width` or `height`, use fix values.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thanks!